# JOLT Transform - pattern matching

Tags: json, jolt

I am trying to transform input fields by matching pattern like **`"*|*|*"`** where the words are separated by **`|`**. However, I am not able to get it working. If I replace **`|`** by **`:`**, the spec works. Is there a special meaning to **`|`**, how can use this as part of regular expressions?

**Input** :

```json
{
  "items": [
    {
      "itemId": "1234500AA",
      "additionalData": "12345|20001|3000"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Spec** :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "items": {
        "*": {
          "itemId": "ID",
          "additionalData": {
            "*|*|*": {
              "$(0,1)": ["cartMenuItems[&3].baseProductId", "cartMenuItems[&3].mdmId"],
              "$(0,2)": "cartMenuItems[&3].code",
              "$(0,3)": "cartMenuItems[&3].sku"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Output Expected** :

```json
{
  "ID": "1234500AA",
  "cartMenuItems": [
    {
      "baseProductId": "12345",
      "mdmId": "12345",
      "code": "20001",
      "sku": "3000"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, I get an error like below:

> ```
> JOLT Chainr encountered an exception constructing Transform  
> className:com.bazaarvoice.jolt.Shiftr at index:0.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Jolt doesn't seem to like **`|`** (as you would need to escape them), you could replace the **`|`** :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "items": {
        "*": {
          "additionalDataTemp": "=split('\\|',@(1,additionalData))",
          "additionalData": "=concat(@(1,additionalDataTemp[0]),'_',@(1,additionalDataTemp[1]),'_',@(1,additionalDataTemp[2]))"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "items": {
        "*": {
          "itemId": "ID",
          "additionalData": {
            "*_*_*": {
              "$(0,1)": ["cartMenuItems[&3].baseProductId", "cartMenuItems[&3].mdmId"],
              "$(0,2)": "cartMenuItems[&3].code",
              "$(0,3)": "cartMenuItems[&3].sku"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Or another way of doing it would be:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "items": {
        "*": {
          "additionalData": "=split('\\|', @(1,additionalData))",
          "baseProductId": "@(1,additionalData[0])",
          "mdmId": "@(1,additionalData[0])",
          "code": "@(1,additionalData[1])",
          "sku": "@(1,additionalData[2])"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "items": {
        "*": {
          "itemId": "ID",
          "*": "cartMenuItems[0].&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "cartMenuItems": {
        "*": {
          "additionalData": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```